# How to perform scroll down using selenium with Node.js and Chai/Mocha framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, mocha.js

Browser: Chrome
Using selenium with Node.js (javascript), how to perform scroll up or down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scroll till element is in view :

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", element);
```

or youcan scroll by pixels :

```
executeScript("window.scrollBy(x-pixels,y-pixels)");
```

or till the end of page:

```
executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Comment: Thank u..it worked with: driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", element);